# search string text in search grid is not working using send keys

Tags: selenium2, java, javascript

I am passing `sendKeys( )` through search grid to search a particular string.I am able to click that search text but its not clicking the search string ,Below is the html for that search text:

```
<input  name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSessionName"
        type="text"
        onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSessionName\',\'\')', 0)"
        onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;"
        id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSessionName"
        class="search-icon"
        placeholder="Session Title/Track Name"
        onkeyup="ShowSearch();"
        title="Session Name"
        autocomplete="off"
        style="width: 300px;">
```

I used with below code but not working:

**First try**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSessionName").sendKeys(searchSessionText);
```

**Second try**

```
WebELment= driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSessionName"));
JavascriptExecutor rightexecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
rightexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','searchSessionText')", Element);
```

**Third try:**

```
WebElement
Element=driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSessionName"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(Element).sendKeys(searchSessionText).build().perform();
```

**Fourth try:**

```
WebElement
Element=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(Element).click().sendKeys(searchSessionText).build().perform();
```

**Fifth try**

```
WebElement Element=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(Element).click(Element).sendKeys(searchSessionText).build().perform();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Is this for a auto-complete in the search box?

Comment: yes this is for autocomplete text box .you can see html snippet on top.

Comment: I think the auto complete is not displaying for enough time to send the click event. Try adding a Key down after sending the search string and then click.

Comment: You can see this answer. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13578/understanding-how-to-handle-auto-complete-using-selenium-and-python

Comment: I used what ever stated in above link but still its not working for me .

Comment: did you try adding a key dowb

Comment: yes i tried keys.down before click but its not working .